# What is the best way to structure a shopping cart to ship to multiple recipients?

Tags: architecture, e-commerce, information-presentation

We are designing a shopping cart that allows customers to ship to multiple recipients, but we are stuck at the conceptual level of the relationship between items in the cart and recipients.

There are two options to consider:

(a) Assign items (child) to each recipient (parent)
(b) Assign recipients (child) to each item (parent)

Option A in essence creates multiple "carts" - one for each recipient. While Option B creates a single cart, but each item has additional details (recipients) attached it it.

Which option is the correct one?

Answer (score 3):

I believe you are thinking of the concept of a "cart" two different ways, and it seems to me that you're missing an entity.

One notion of the concept of a cart relates (line items) to an order that hasn't yet been submitted, and another notion of the cart as you seem to be describing it, is a grouping of items intended for one recipient or shipping address.

Thus, there are really three entities here with some relationships: cart, recipient, and (shipping) bundle, where the bundle organizes and groups items of an order with a recipient.

Sometimes when we get stuck with modeling relationships, it is because we are conflating entities, and so we need to consider splitting an entity into two (or more) different concepts — that can make it easier to understand the relationships.  By using two different entities, we may not only be able to tease out the proper relationships but also separate the timing / lifetime of these different entities.  For example, the shipping bundles can be created/organized independently of the cart itself, as desired: either as part of adding items to the cart, or even after the order is submitted (i.e. as part of a multi step order submission process).

Answer (score 2):

How do the business rules interact with your data?

Prefer the data structure that supports those business rules to be expressed.

For example if the business rules prefer to directly relate items to addresses without a shopping cart. Then it is against the grain to put the address on the cart.

Alternately if the business rules prefer to handle the items as a cart that is shipped to an address. Then it is against the grain to have addresses set on each item.

If the Rules want both, then good luck one will be easier, the other more complex.

Comment: Thanks! At this stage, it's more conceptual, and we can adjust the underlying business rules as need be. I guess what we're trying to determine, is which approach is more intuitive for the user?

Comment: @MattP The user doesn't have to care what your data model is. The UI is probably going to display some metaphor for the relationship between items and recipients, at which point  `class Item { Recipient recipient }` vs `class Recipient { Items items }` is indistinguishable

Comment: @Caleth I think the question isn’t really about the data model, but more about the UI/UX.

Answer (score 1):

> (a) Assign items (child) to each recipient (parent)

> Option A in essence creates multiple "carts" - one for each recipient.

It doesn't create multiple carts. Not unless you decide to conflate the `Cart` and `Recipient` entities.

But if you do that, then you're doing the opposite of what you're asking about here, i.e. "**a** shopping cart to ship to **multiple** recipients".

So it seems to me like option A, while possible on a technical level, is not actually an implementation of the thing you're looking to implement here.

---

> Which option is the correct one?

There is no "correct one". There are multiple ways to go about this. The two that stick out the most are:

*Note that I use `>` and `<` as a shorthand for one-to-many relationships. The open end is the "many".*

```
Cart < Recipient < Item
```

In human terms, you add a bunch of recipients to a cart, and then allocate your cart items to these recipients rather than to the cart itself.

```
Cart < Item > Recipient
```

In human terms, you have add your items to the cart directly, but each item must be assigned a specific recipient. Whether you allow this to be done at a later stage or only at the time of adding the item to the cart, is up to you to decide.

Your question does not contain enough context to favor one specific approach here. Some possible considerations:

- If you want the same recipient to be reused across multiple carts, option 2 is much more desirable.
- If you specifically want recipients to be cart-specific and want to block reuse, either option is fine, but option 1 is slightly more straightforward as option 2 would then also require a third relation between a cart and its recipients.
- If a customer adds cart items before even wanting to assign a recipient, option 2 is more desirable.
- If you need any recipient-specific handling, e.g. the ability for the customer to pay for the items for Bob, but not those for Andy (yet), option 1 is more desirable.

The short summary here is that your design is best decided based on how closely it mirrors the sequence of operations that you want your customer to go through. For example, option 1 is starkly different from the approach where a customer adds items to a cart well before they consider who the recipient is.

The more different your data design is from your actually intended usage, the more effort you're going to have to put in to write logic that manually has to juggle the data. Less juggling is obviously better.

---

I also suspect that you may not have fully worked out the conceptual difference between a `Cart` and an `Order`, and how you structure those two can influence the above decision.

For example, you might consider your cart as an "unpaid order", this works well enough for small webshops while keeping the technical footprint down. This also makes it easy to transfer your recipient-categorization between a cart and an order (since they're the same entity, just one has been confirmed paid and the other hasn't been).

However, for administration's sake, you might want to explicitly separate the cart and order tables, which is more common in large-scale webshops.
Here, the question becomes whether you need carts *and* orders to be subdivided by recipient, or whether you only introduce this subdivision when turning a cart into an actual order.

These are things that needs to be analyzed and weighed against each other. The question does not contain the information needed to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this talk, as it relates to modelling the shopping cart conceptually.  A bit of a spoiler is that shopping cart does not exist as a thing and that your recipients are shipping details I think, but it is hard for me to say because I do not know much about your application use. I hope you will find it useful.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KkzvQSuYd5I

Answer (score 0):

Look at the cardinalities of the recipient-item relation. I'd guess (unless you have a very weird concept of item) that each item has exactly one recipient, but each recipient can have multiple items.

This suggests that option (a) would match requirements best.

Conceptually, I would associate a cart with the billing process (i.e. all items in the cart are paid for in one sum) and a recipient with the shipping process (all items for one recipient are packed and delivered to one address).

```
Cart
+--- Recipients
     +--- Items
```